# How to increase the size of play and pause buttons and the height of an HTML audio player?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-audio

As you can see, the PLAY/PAUSE icons are too small than intended as well as the whole player is thiner than intended as some viewer will have difficulties to see it. How can I make the whole player bigger? I read that we will not have access to individual controls (eg. Play)

[image]

What I want is the WHOLE audio player to be bigger where the PLAY/PAUSE ICONS as well as the SLIDER is more easly visible for everyone.

***EDITED with webkit media control styles***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
    audio::-webkit-media-controls-play-button {
        transform: scale(2, 2);
    }

    audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {
        height: 20px;
    }

</style>

<body>

    <h1>The audio element</h1>


    <audio controls controlsList="nodownload noplaybackrate" style="width:600px;">
        <source
            src="https://content.production.cdn.art19.com/segment_lists/d4e00ef7-1edc-41c2-b4c4-505f1742d71d/20220607-VGhlVGltRmVycmlzc1Nob3dfSW5zaWdodHMgZXAgMV9lZGl0ICgxKS5tcDM-697d12ab-6cb9-4ec3-8856-2bbd8d9c4152.mp3"
            type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>

</body>

</html>
```

***With the webkit audio control styles applied, the player now looks like as follows:***

[image]

**How can I fix that timeline(darker) to be of same size(height) as the gray, think timeline?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19315305/how-to-increase-the-height-of-the-html-audiotag may be relevant

Comment: As is the styling guidance in the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#styling_with_css

Comment: Thank you @tacoshy and yes i saw both prior to posting this but it didn't help me. I also commented on first link's answer that when i set height to 300px, the only thing it does it pull down the audio control down to the page. I was thinking if someone has a work around to make the player as a whole bigger and easly visible.

Comment: `it didn't help me`....because? The guidance seems clear: you can't style the the audio player with default controls because it is browser-native. If you want to make your own style you need to also make your own controls. Pretty much the only thing you can adjust with the default audio player and browser-generated controls is the width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is custom styling for the `audio` tag. You can use `audio::-webkit-media-controls-play-button` to modify the play button itself, and you can use `audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline` for the timeline like so:

```css
audio::-webkit-media-controls-play-button {
    transform: scale(2, 2);
}

audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {
    height: 20px;
    transform: scale(1, 1.5);  
}
```

```html
<h1>The audio element</h1>


<audio controls controlsList="nodownload noplaybackrate" style="width:600px;">
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

If you would like to make the whole audio player bigger, you can do this simply by doing the following:

```css
audio {
    position: relative;
    right: -600px;
    transform: scale(3, 3);
}
```

```html
<audio controls controlsList="nodownload noplaybackrate" style="width:600px;">
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

With the webkit controls, you can also make each item bigger if you want to make the whole player bigger. All of the webkit audio modifications allowed can be found below.

```
audio::-webkit-media-controls-panel
audio::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button
audio::-webkit-media-controls-play-button
audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline-container
audio::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display
audio::-webkit-media-controls-time-remaining-display
audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline
audio::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider-container
audio::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider
audio::-webkit-media-controls-seek-back-button
audio::-webkit-media-controls-seek-forward-button
audio::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button
audio::-webkit-media-controls-rewind-button
audio::-webkit-media-controls-return-to-realtime-button
audio::-webkit-media-controls-toggle-closed-captions-button
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you @Infui0ayaan, its very close but the timeline when playing the audio remain thin and darker than the timeline (shown thicker when running with your change).  I updated the sample code in my original post with your changes and please play the audio and you will see the issue.

Comment: Hey @KorefKoref, I am not very sure how to fix this issue, I do not know if there is a webkit control that directly changes the timeline slider... however, you can try and test out some of the `audio::-webkit-media-controls` that I supplied above. If that does not work, maybe try using a `progress` tag in place of the timeline slider, though, you will need Javascript to make the progress bar interactive.

Comment: thanks! I used yours and figured out to properly render it. But its so close to yours. for timeline, using height resulted in the issue i reported above but using transform: scale() made it work as follows.  `audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {
    transform: scale(1, 1.5); 
}`
Please correct yours so i can accept it. I don't want to take your credit.

Comment: Alright, has been corrected. Glad to know that I helped

Answer (score 1):

As others have written, the player which is loaded when using the HTML `<audio>` element is created by the browser, therefore looks different in each browser and is extremely limited concerning the possibility of affecting its layout via CSS.

If you want to create a really individual audio player, there is a jQuery plugin called "jPlayer" which can be found here: https://jplayer.org/

You need some tweaking capabilities to apply it, but it really allows you to use your own graphics and CSS for all player elements. It seems old on first sight (well: it *is* old), but has been working (and still is) on two of my websites without the need to update/change it in more than ten years...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Johannes. But because of policy, i can't pull separate package for it.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers provide different [default audio players](https://css-tricks.com/lets-create-a-custom-audio-player/). You cannot simply change all properties using basic CSS.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#styling_with_css:

> You can style the default controls with properties that affect the block as a single unit, so for example you can give it a border and border-radius, padding, margin, etc. **You can't however style the individual components inside the audio player (e.g. change the button size or icons, change the font, etc.), and the controls are different across the different browsers.**
>
> **To get a consistent look and feel across browsers, you'll need to create custom controls; these can be marked up and styled in whatever way you want**, and then JavaScript can be used along with the HTMLMediaElement API to wire up their functionality.

There are some examples on the web of how you can style audio players using custom controls, e.g. on Codepen.io and how to use the API to change the state.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Video_and_audio_APIs:

> Part of the HTML5 spec, the HTMLMediaElement API provides features to allow you to control video and audio players programmatically — for example HTMLMediaElement.play(), HTMLMediaElement.pause(), etc. This interface is available to both  and  elements, as the features you'll want to implement are nearly identical. Let's go through an example, adding features as we go.

Unfortunately, it's not super trivial to create the HTML, style it, and use javascript to control the audio using the API.

```
One of many custom audio player examples on Codepen:
https://codepen.io/ozzie/pen/YPOBEJ
```

Comment: Thank you @Christian. I understand that and I am not to style "individual components" either. I just want to make it bigger the whole thing as a unit and was looking if there was some work around. The sample code is a progress bar but won't have capabilities of what the audio control can such as dragging back and forth to jump around starting point (as needed).

Comment: Oh sorry for the wrong link. I have added an example of custom audio controls to my post. I have also linked the HTMLMediaElement API documentation.

Comment: In the example above, you can remove some unwanted HTML, keep the controls, and change the CSS style definitions to be able to better understand the things you are looking for, e.g. buttons and size definitions for both controls and the status bar.